# How to hide the GCVirtualController

Tags: swift, gamekit

I have a virtual controller displayed in this way:

```
let virtualConfiguration = GCVirtualController.Configuration()
    virtualConfiguration.elements = [GCInputLeftThumbstick,
                                     GCInputRightThumbstick,
                                     GCInputButtonA,
                                     GCInputButtonB,
                                     GCInputButtonX,
                                     GCInputButtonY,
    ]
    
    virtualController =  GCVirtualController(configuration:virtualConfiguration)
    
    virtualController?.connect() 
    virtualController?.disconnect()
```

Everything works well but how to make it disappear afterwards?

If I use this line just after the pad remains visible and does not disappear...

```
virtualController?.disconnect()
```

How to make it disappear?

Thanks